# Scrape excel files

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to download a series of excel files sitting behind a number of links on this webpage: https://www.grants.gov.au/reports/gaweeklyexport

When I follow the tutorials online I am able to get the text of the first link in the list, but no more. Can anyone help me to write the code that will list each of the addresses to the excel files?

For instance; success for the first link looks like this: https://www.grants.gov.au/Reports/GaWeeklyExportDownload?GaWeeklyExportUuid=0db183a2-11c6-42f8-bf52-379aafe0d21b

But I also need the other links in that list.

My attempt, that only finds the first item on the list:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.grants.gov.au/reports/gaweeklyexport"

webpage <- read_html(url)

html_text(html_node(webpage, '.u'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use `html_nodes()` rather than `html_node()` to get all matching elements.

You may also want to use `html_attr()` rather than `html_text()` to get the URL rather than the text in the link, as in:

```
html_attr(html_nodes(webpage, '.u'), "href")
```